# How to show kubernetes node names instead of AWS hosts in Datadog - EKS integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, datadog

I'm running AWS EKS and trying to integrate it with Datadog.

Kubernetes operates with node names, so

```
> kubectl get nodes
NAME                                     STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal    Ready    <none>   1d    v1.21.1-eks
```

But all the metrics in Datadog have AWS instance id in `host` tag, like `host:i-012aa34a56a789a0a`

And when I see something in the Datadog, I'd like to find the node in kubernetes cluster and investigate deeper inside the node.
For example, to get all the pods in the node

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeName=ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

But Datadog gives me only `host:i-012aa34a56a789a0a`.

Is there a way to convert `host:i-012aa34a56a789a0a` into `ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal`?

Comment: IPs can change. Host ids cannot. You can find the associated host information such as the most recent agent IP from the agents /hosts dashboards in Datadog

Comment: Alternative solution would be to tag/annotate your kubelet nodes with their host ID, then use that as your field selector

Comment: Pod name changes as well, but still metrics have pod name tags, so that doesn't look like a reason. Add other way round tagging helps a bit, but still does not allow filtering pods by node name because I have to find node by host name first - doesn't seem convenient. Moreover, adding such node tags seems like a custom operation, I don't see a standard way of doing that.